# Net::SSH interactive terminal scripting. How?

Tags: ruby, ssh

i have several managed network switches, and i want to batch configure them via SSH.
Normal SSH connection in an interactive tty is no problem. But it seems that i can't just
`ssh user@host command` because they do not recognize the command properly. So it has to be an interactive session.

Now i have ruby and the Net::SSH library. The simple `exec!`command does not work, either. 
So i think i need to emulate an interactive terminal with the switches. But i don't know where to start.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Try [expect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/). You'd better explain with example how your "command does not work", how they fail.

Comment: The command was not executed by the target host. I don't know why. `ssh -vvv` told me that the host, which is an embedded device failed while reading any command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried `expect`. Great tool. Helped me.