# Interactive SSH session using Net::SSH or creating a STDIN Socket

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

This is not a duplicate of [How to SSH interactive Session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7941927/681520) or [Net::SSH interactive terminal scripting. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15679948/681520) or [Ruby net-ssh interactive response/reply](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47717025/681520)

I'm trying to write an interactive SSH client using Net:SSH, because I'm already using it for run non-interactive commands on the target hosts.

I could just shell out to `system "ssh"` but it would require converting the connection settings, proxying, etc to `ssh` params.

The problem is streaming the data from `STDIN` to the shell channel. The Net::SSH documentation for [`listen_to`](https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Session.html#M000096) shows how to do it when the input is from a socket instead of STDIN. `$stdin` or `IO.console` are not sockets and thus not compatible with `Net::SSH::BufferedIo`.

Is there a way to create a socket from `STDIN` that can be used for this? Or is there a better way to send everything from the `STDIN` to the `Net::SSH::Channel` until the channel closes?

Here's code that works, but is way too slow to be usable:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'io/console'
require 'io/wait'

Net::SSH.start('localhost', 'root') do |session|
  session.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.on_data do |_, data|
      $stdout.write(data)
    end

    channel.on_extended_data do |_, data|
      $stdout.write(data)
    end

    channel.request_pty do
      channel.send_channel_request "shell"
    end

    channel.connection.loop do
      $stdin.raw do |io|
        input = io.readpartial(1024)
        channel.send_data(input) unless input.empty?
      end
      channel.active?
    end
  end.wait
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets are really nothing more than file descriptors, and since STDIN is a file descriptor too, it doesn't hurt to try.

What you want however, is to put the TTY into raw mode first to get interactivity.
This code seems to work fine:

```
begin
  system('stty cbreak -echo')

  Net::SSH.start(...) do |session|
    session.open_channel do |...|
       ...
       session.listen_to(STDIN) { |stdin|
         input = stdin.readpartial(1024)
         channel.send_data(input) unless input.empty?
       }
     end.wait
   end
ensure
  system('stty sane')
end
```

Comment: Should have tried without the `Net::SSH::BufferedIo` which caused a `NoMethodError` for `STDIN.recv`. Looks like that works. The `stty` stuff, I believe can be replaced with `$stdin.raw!; $stdin.echo = false;`. Thanks!